# php nested objects function call not working?

Tags: php, oop, class, inner-classes, function-call

I have a PHP class that can contain an array of its own type this class has also a function called `hatch()` when I call it for one of the array items it gives me a message you can't call the function. I call it like that

```
$this->arrayLikeThis[$i]->hatch();
```

however I made an outer function to hatch the object but I love to call it that way. I know that I can call any function of the the `var_dump()` of the class is like that:

```
object(web\ui\structure\tag)#1 (4) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "meta"
  ["type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(web\ui\structure\attribute)#2 (2) {
      ["attributeName"]=>
      string(7) "content"
      ["attributeValue"]=>
      string(24) "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(web\ui\structure\attribute)#3 (2) {
      ["attributeName"]=>
      string(10) "http-equiv"
      ["attributeValue"]=>
      string(12) "Content-Type"
    }
  }
  ["childNodes"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's your code and what's the exact error?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($this->arrayLikeThis[$i]);` ?

Comment: Based on output you've posted I could tell that you have objects only in `arrayLikeThis['attributes']` array

Comment: Could you also post the code where you create the objects to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluffeh is right, your code should work fine if it's actually a reference to the class (which I highly doubt that it is). Here's an example that simulates what your class might look like (with the same functions and in an array).

```
<?php
    class egg {
        private $identifier;
        private $eggChildren = array();
        public function __construct($identifier) {
            $this->identifier = $identifier;
        }
        public function createEgg($identifier) {
            $this->eggChildren[$identifier] = new egg($this->identifier . " - " . $identifier);
        }
        public function hatch() {
            echo "Just hatched egg with ID " . $this->identifier . "<br />";
        }
        public function hatchAllChildren() {
            foreach ($this->eggChildren as $childID => $eggChild) {
                $eggChild->hatch();
            }
        }
    }
    class eggs {
        private $arrayLikeThis;
        const COUNT_EGGS = 3;
        const COUNT_EGG_CHILDREN = 3;
        public function createEggs() {
            $this->arrayLikeThis = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < self::COUNT_EGGS; $i++) {
                $this->arrayLikeThis[$i] = new egg($i);
                for ($j = 0; $j < self::COUNT_EGG_CHILDREN; $j++) { 
                    $this->arrayLikeThis[$i]->createEgg($j);
                }
            }
        }
        public function hatchEggs() {
            for ($i = 0; $i < self::COUNT_EGGS; $i++) {
                $this->arrayLikeThis[$i]->hatchAllChildren();
                $this->arrayLikeThis[$i]->hatch();
            }
        }
    }

    $eggController = new eggs();
    $eggController->createEggs();
    $eggController->hatchEggs();
?>
```

And this will output

```
Just hatched egg with ID 0 - 0
Just hatched egg with ID 0 - 1
Just hatched egg with ID 0 - 2
Just hatched egg with ID 0
Just hatched egg with ID 1 - 0
Just hatched egg with ID 1 - 1
Just hatched egg with ID 1 - 2
Just hatched egg with ID 1
Just hatched egg with ID 2 - 0
Just hatched egg with ID 2 - 1
Just hatched egg with ID 2 - 2
Just hatched egg with ID 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specifying the actual object, just the array of objects:

```
$this->arrayLikeThis[identifier]->hatch();
```

where `identifier` is either a number if your array is numeric, or the name of the element that contains the object whose function you want to call.

I snapped up this example for you just now to show you:

```
<?php  
    class arby
    {
        public $myID=0;
        public $ray=array();

        public function insertNew()
        {
            $this->ray[0] = new arby();
        }

        public function updateMe()
        {
            $this->myID='1';
        }

        public function displayMe()
        {
            echo $this->myID."\n";
        }

    }

    $var= new arby();
    $var->displayMe();
    $var->insertNew();
    $var->ray[0]->updateMe();
    $var->ray[0]->displayMe();


?>
```

which outputs:

```
0
1
```

This covers off a class that can have instances of itself within it, adding these into an array and calling functions from within them and individual objects within the array of objects.

Edit: Assuming that the `hatch()` function is a function within the `attribute` object, this should work:

```
$varName->attributes[0]->hatch();
```

Edit: Assuming that there were *further* instances of `arby` within the second one that I made you can call the functions from them like this:

```
$var->ray[0]->ray[1]->hatch();
```

This assumes that the variable `$var` has another instance of the `arby` class in the array element `0` which in turn has another array and you want to call the function of the object in the element `1` this time.

Comment: sorry but i forgot to put it in the question i've done that i'll update the question

thank you.

Comment: @Romany1St Just to make sure, the `hatch()` function is in the `attribute` object yes - or is it in the `childNodes` object? If it is the latter, then your var_dump doesn't show any that have been created using `= new tag();` which means that the object isn't set - hence you can't call it's functions.

Comment: @Romany1St I have included an example of code that will allow you to call functions inside a third level of objects if you need. This might help clear it up for you.

Comment: Thanks man it was about the `foreach` loop instead of for `loop`